# Custom loop not working

Tags: loop, meta-query

So I've created a custom loop where posts of my custom post type will appear *and* posts where I've declared the value 'synopsis' to the meta 'layout_meta_box'. The custom post type is working, but the meta box value is not working. What did I do wrong?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Archief Synopsis
Template Post Type: algemeen
*/
get_header();
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'televisie',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'layout_meta_box' => 'synopsis',
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?> 
    <div class="container-fluid-limited">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-article">
                <h1>Alle artikels over <?php post_type_archive_title(); ?></h1>
                <?php
                if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) :
                        $custom_query->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'excerpt' );
                    endwhile;
                else :
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none');
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 sidebar">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: `layout_meta_box` is not a part of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: That's my custom meta value, I thought I could do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'televisie',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'meta_key'     => 'layout_meta_box',
  'meta_value'   => 'synopsis',
);
```

A helpful article too:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/custom-loop-based-on-custom-fields/

Comment: Just updated again. Try with 'meta_key' or just 'meta'. Can't remember right now which is needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're my hero! For the record: both `meta` and `meta_key` are working.